# Custom UITableViewCell label color animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uitableview

I've added 3 UILabels to a custom UITableViewCell and I'm trying to animate the textColors of those UILabels.

The last thing I tried was this piece of code in the setSelected and/or the setHighlighted method:

```
UIColor *shadowColor;
UIColor *textColor;
if (highlightedOrSelected) {
    shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:33.0/255.0 blue:6.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
} else {
    shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:33.0/255.0 blue:6.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.3 : 0.0
                 animations:^{
                     self.label1.shadowColor = shadowColor;
                     self.label1.textColor = textColor;

                     self.label2.shadowColor = shadowColor;
                     self.label2.textColor = textColor;

                     self.label3.shadowColor = shadowColor;
                     self.label3.textColor = textColor;
                 }];
```

The animation just fails, I also tried a hardcoded 10.0 duration, but still no animation.

What am I doing wrong and how do I get this to work?

Comment: You are changing the color when it changes from highlighted to normal and vice versa. If the state doesn’t change, this code doesn’t work right? Have you checked for it?

Comment: Yes, the state is changing. Logs and break points got called. *Edit: maybe I wasn't clear enough in the OP, but only the animation isn't happening. The change of colors, however, does happen.

Comment: Maybe you should use animateWithDuration: animation:^{} completion:^{}

Comment: I'm sorry Nina, but that won't change a thing, since my animation block will (probably) call animateWithDuration:animation:completion:nil by itself.

Comment: Oh.. Then probably it would be the duration (falling to ‘0’).. but you mentioned you tried it with 10.0 as well.. Clueless...